# Get SIM card connection info

Tags: mobile-data, sim-card, 3g, 4g, 2g

If I want to know if I am connected 2G, 3G or 4G, how do I check that on Android?

I don't seem to have any default SIM-related app on my phone, nor does the SIM setting screen give much information other than APN details (`APN type` says "default").

I'm using FlymeOS 6.1 (Chinese ROM based on 5.1 Lollipop).

Answer (score 0):

There is information under `About phone`->`Status`->`SIM Status`.

The relevant field is `Cellular network type`.

3g if:

- UMTS
- HSPA
- W-CDMA

2g if:

- EDGE
- GPRS
- GSM